# How to generate the downloaded pdf from react-pdf without clicking the download link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

I'm currently creating a pdf using react-pdf. Instead of providing a download link with the PDFDownloadLink component, I want to run the program and have it automatically create and download the pdf. I'm not very familiar with react, is there a way I can have it click the link once it is rendered? Is there a better way? Ideally, I'd like to create a command like "yarn generate" and it outputs the pdf that gets rendered. Any help is appreciated!

```
import React from 'react';
import { BlobProvider, PDFDownloadLink, PDFViewer} from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import './App.css';
import { MyPDF} from "./components/MyPDF";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <PDFDownloadLink document={<MyPDF/>} fileName="mypdf.pdf">
          {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => {
            console.log(blob);
            return (loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download the pdf')}
            }
        </PDFDownloadLink>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```